# Class-based Projections (DTOs) id not working but Interface based projections is working

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am using simple class based projections For native SQL explained here.
https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections
But  i am getting below exception

`caused by: org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type`

**Value Object**

```
@EqualsAndHashCode
@Value
public class MyClass{
    private String someName;
}
```

**Repository**

```
public interface MyRepository extends JpaRepository<MyClass,Long> {  
    @Query(value = "select SOME_NAME From Some_table where ID=1795463580",nativeQuery = true)
    public List<MyClass> getsomeName();

}
```

I removed lombok from MyClass, Still it does not works.

Now If i Change `MyClass` to `Interface`  it works

```
 public interface MyClass{
        public String getSomeName();
    }
```

Comment: Which version of Spring Boot are you using?

Comment: Spring Boot 2.1.5.RELEASE